# Can't display image after uploading it to a data base, PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, database, image, upload

I need to do a web page for a client to upload images to a data base and display them.

I am achieve to upload the images into a database, but I'm having trouble displaying them, but I can't work out why

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <body>

    <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File:
        <input type="file" name="image" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>

    <?php 
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("test" ) or die(mysql_error());

        $file = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

        if (!isset($file)) {
            echo "<br>Please select an image.";
        }
        else {
            $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']));
            $imageName = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $imageSize = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

            if ($imageSize == FALSE)
                echo "<br><br>Thats not an image. <br><br>";


            else{
                if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO imgup VALUES ('','$imageName','$image')"))
                    echo "Problem uploading the image.";
                else{
                    $lastId = mysql_insert_id();
                    echo "Article uploaded.<p /> Your image:<p /> <img src=get.php?id=$lastId>";
                }
            }
        }

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my file who turn the image blob into an image:

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("test" ) or die(mysql_error());

        $id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);


        $image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=$id");
        $image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
        $image = $image['image'];

        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

        echo $image;

?>
```

And at the end the image does not display and this is what i get: http://goo.gl/gi1Uuc

And if i go and check my database, the image has ben successfully uploaded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the file use inline base64 encoding. This is done with:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $image ).'"/>';
```

Font: [base64_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php)

OR

Put the `T` upperCase (Type), because can giving error in IE. Try printing with the function file_get_contents.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo readfile($image);
```

Comment: @user3479756 Check your BLOB is not being recorded corrupted.

Comment: @user3479756 It is JPEG? Or PNG?

Comment: How could i do that? i've trying only with jpg files, do you know any other way to achieve the same result? my intention is to make a "blog" so people can upload articles into their web page (that i will make it too)

Comment: @user3479756 One way to deal with that is to create a checksum of the files before putting them into the blob to be able later on to verify the data-integrity, but the best way is to leave the file in the directory and save just the path or name.

Comment: okey i tried with readfile, and nothing happens, i think i'll try with the path, do you know any tutorial for that? cause im a little lost here, and i've think of that before but i just don't know how to let know the php that a file has been uploaded so the php could store the path of the new file, i don't know if i made my self clear

Comment: @user3479756 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545582/how-to-upload-image-code-and-save-path-into-mysql-db and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737462/how-to-upload-image-php-and-insert-path-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't store any image in a database. You should save it as file, and store the file's name in the database. You can then configure which directory an image gets served from without worrying about the full path to the image, or storing binary data in your db (yuck).

Comment: Hi Ryan, i have think of that before but i have no idea how to do it, do you know any tutorial of how to do that? i would appreciate that, thank you

Comment: I don't know of any tutorials, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Let's say someone tries to upload a file and the path to your webspace is /path/to/document_root. You want to use move_uploaded_file in something like move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file'], '/path/to/document_root/uploaded/'.$uploaded_file_name). Then when you access it, you want to use it on the front end, you refer to it by 'http://yourdomain.com/uploaded/'.$uploaded_file_name. You don't want anything that isn't indexable in your database. You want indexable references to your binary data in your database. So you store $uploaded_file_name in a column, and store the path and url to it in scripts

Comment: I meant $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], not $_FILES['file'].

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=$id");
```

to:

```
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping an image file with `addslashes` will probably corrupt it, the `imagesize` test should be sufficient

Comment: hey! thank you for the advise, unfortunately if i remove the addslashes the image just don't upload and send me back the "Problem uploading the image." error