# Getting image from MySQL in PHP results in damaged image

Tags: php, mysql, http-headers

I'm stuck with the error

> "The image “....image.php?id=1878” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

This is the code I am retrieving the image content from the db. The data in db is correct, because the same file displays perfectly with some old php code. In fact, the code I use is the same exact old code, I just extracted it from many linked(included) php files and obviously I am missing something.

```
$query="SELECT image_original_file, mime_type, {$field_content} as content, {$field_content}_md5 as imhash, CHAR_LENGTH({$field_content}) as leng  FROM IMAGES WHERE ID_image={$_GET['id']}";
$res=mysql_query($query,DB_CON);
$myRow = mysql_fetch_row($res);
//Of course this echo statement is just for debuging, as echo causes the default headers to be sent.
echo "Fetched content length:".mb_strlen($myRow[2])." and MySQL length ".$myRow[4];
list($name,$type,$content,$imhash,$length)=$myRow;
```

The output here shows that the content length in php is 29179bytes, but in MySQL it is 28605 (which is the correct size when I save the image).
I wonder why the size of the content is different in PHP after those lines of code. The filecontent in DB is not base64 encoded, nor does the original code use any manipulation on the content retrieved from the db. I compared the Headers of the old code and the "new" code, everything except the content length is the same. I suspect this ia some sort of characterset problem?

I tried:

```
 mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
 mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", DB_CON);
 mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8",DB_CON);
```

But the problem persists. I will be very happy for some advice.

The image is sent to the browser like this:

```
header("ETag: \"{$imhash}\"");
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Length: ".mb_strlen($content));
header("Content-Type: {$type}");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"{$name}\";");
echo $content;
```

Comment: what's the field type of your image field? If it's text, then any bytes in the BINARY data of the image that LOOK like they're valid text will be subject to charset translation rules. binary data should be stored in blob/binary fields, not text.

Comment: Totally off topic : Why on earth are you storing images in a database??? The filesystem is a database itself, Save a reference in a table, like a `filename`, and `save`, `load` (get), `delete`, `restore` your images from the server filesystem itself.

Comment: @MarcB the mime type is Content-Type image/jpeg, $type = image/jpeg
 the problem is the old site does this, and I have to keep the old content of the site while moving to a new CMS, so I need this image.php script to work in order for the old content to show images.

Comment: @davidkonrad please see comment above

Comment: that's not what I'm asking. what is the type of the field in your database?

Comment: @MarcB oh, sorry...it is mediumblob

Comment: This Q&A may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419560/cant-display-image-after-uploading-it-to-a-data-base-php-and-mysql - I think you also may be outputting before header or just a bad/malformed set of headers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- is it possible to output anything by any php warning or error message without that output being visible and still get the correct image/jpeg headers? Cause the headers as shown by Firebug are correct and correspond to the ones I set.

Comment: You're using mb_strlen on binary data. that's non-sensical... like I said - binary data CAN/will contain byte sequences that LOOK like legitimate multi-byte character sequences. mb_strlen is for STRINGS of TEXT, not binary data. use `strlen()` instead, which is NOT multi-byte aware and will basically just count the raw bytes in your image data.

Comment: If you're trying to echo an image and text (or any type of output) at the same time using header, then that would be the reason why.

Comment: @MarcB in fact the old code used strlen(), I changed while looking for a solution, this does not solve the problem, just switched back. And strlen() reports the same size as mb_strlen() in this case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not doing any other output bymyself I just could imagine PHP throwing some warning message. I will try to turn off all error messaging.

Comment: I guess by having errors somewhere, counts as output and PHP/SQL are fighting to gain control over what should be displayed. Errors win over anything. *That's my take on it* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- just added error_reporting(0); still no luck.

Comment: The actual image data output is different between your two sites.  Maybe an encoding issue.  Try `BINARY {$field_content} as content`

Comment: On second glance it looks like it's an escaping issue, not an encoding issue. You need to figure out why the image data has escaped things like quotes `\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image data is being escaped so for example the quote character `"` is being turned into `\"` which corrupts the image.

Make sure `magic_quotes_gpc`, `magic_quotes_runtime`, and `magic_quotes_sybase` are not `On` in your php.ini configuration file.

[PHP Magic Quote Directives](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)

Comment: Thank you very much. I read about the possible esacpe cause, but had a quick glance at the settings which showed that magic_quotes_gpc is off. I did not check for magic_quotes_runtime, which was "ON". So adding this "set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);" to the code fixed the issue. So much lost time on this one.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I added the other two directives to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was really lost with this one. I wish I had figured it out, but you did ;-)